# How to achieve required in select box in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the following template in Angular 5 app:

```
<div class="form-group">    
    <select [(ngModel)]="trip.country.code" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCountry($event)" name="country" required>
        <option>Please select...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value= {{c.country.code}}>{{c.country.name}}</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

As you can see above, I have countries list and another option to inform the user to select. The problem is that I'm not sure how/when Angular make this field mark as invalid ?
I select "Please select..." and I can see in the developer tools that the class is ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid
Thanks!

Comment: If "Please select" isn't an option, don't offer it as an option. Use the (floating) placeholder instead.

Comment: @user post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. My guess is that you have an actual code in trip.country.code, which is not part of the list of selectable code.

Comment: If I remove the option "Please select.." the select will be always valid cause there will be country selected (the first one). I would like to show error if the user didn't select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also came across similar problem in our application we resolved it with the following approach.

The first select option we want it but we don't want to accept it as a valid input.  so just mark it disable which will make the option available to user but the end user will not be able to select it. code as follow :

```
<option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Please select...</option>
```

[check this example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53475891?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: In your example I can see the class ng-invalid attached which is good but in my code it is ng-valid which the "Please select..." is selecte. I have the following classes ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-dirty

Comment: as @Ingo Bürk mentioned don't give it as a option since it is not a valid input.